# Android message between 2 activities problem

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, bundle

I have the following code in one activity:

```
        in= new Intent(ThisActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
        imgarr = new ImageView[55];

        imgarr[0]=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.species3);
        imgarr[0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b.putString("specno",Integer.toString(0)); in.putExtras(b);
                in.setClassName("com.DuckHuntersJournal","com.DuckHuntersJournal._1_TagKillActivity");
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
```

And this code in another:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu1tagkill);

        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey("specno")) {
        Log.e(tag, "intent from species not null");
        species.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("specno"));
    }
```

However, savedInstanceState is null.

 Why am I not getting any data back from the first activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use :

```
   getIntent().getExtras().getString("specno");
```

in order to get the passed string from the first activity.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure what you are trying to do... for getting data from another `Activity` that started the current one you need to use `getIntent().getExtras()`.

For saving your current stat when the `Activity` goes to background you save the data in the [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) method and then in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` method you get the saved data from the `savedInstance` parameter.

Comment: should I do it on savedInstanceState?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do the following in your receiving Activity:

```
String species = getIntent().getStringExtra("specno");
```